# How select and highlight one or more paragraph when touch at text in textview

Tags: android, textview

How select and highlight one or more paragraph when touch at text in textview android code
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea..
Insert HTML code for color, then set this to your text . 
`"<font color='red'>"+textToHighlight+"</font>"` inside your code.

**OR**

Add an EditText with a TextView background, 
For eg).,

```
<EditText 
android:text=" This is not an editable EditText" 
android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
android:editable = "false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background = "@android:drawable/dark_header">
</EditText>
```

add this to your xml in the place of TextView

**OR**

Enable TextView's Spannable storage.(by default Spannable storage in EditText is true.)

```
TextView myTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String  textString = "StackOverFlow Rocks!!!"; 
Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(textString);
spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 14, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myTV.setText(spanText);
```